# You need me. What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> I am usually roseate,
>
> But not always.
>
> I am sometimes inconsiderate;
>
> But you need me.
>
> I protect my jewel
>
> That sometimes moves
>
> Because without it;
>
> I cannot confess,
>
> To my lover;
>
> All the love I have prepared.
>
> After I confess;
>
> I part,
>
> And I love.

<sub>*(This is my first riddle, so it might be easy or a bit off. If it is, please tell me how to improve it!)*</sub>

Comment: You should save the hint for later, if puzzlers can't figure out the puzzle.

Comment: Nice first riddle! Welcome to Puzzline SE!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you ...

> Lips?

I am usually roseate,
But not always.

> Lips are usually pink/rosy, but may be colored with lipstick

I am sometimes inconsiderate;

> A cruel expression

But you need me.

> Necessary for proper eating and speaking

I protect my jewel
That sometimes moves

> The jewel is the tongue

Because without it; I cannot confess,
To my lover;
All the love I have prepared.

> You can't confess your love without a tongue :(

After I confess;
I part,
And I love.

> Lips parting for a kiss

Comment: Yes!!!! You got it rightttttt

Comment: That makes a bit more sense :)

Answer (score 7):

Not sure, but I like this answer anyway:

> An eggshell

...

I am usually roseate,
But not always.

> Eggshells are usually pinkish in colour, (the typical chicken egg), but other birds lay different coloured eggs.

I am sometimes inconsiderate;
But you need me.

> Without the eggshell, the bird/reptile inside would die

I protect my jewel
That sometimes moves

> The yolk is the golden jewel, and occasionally when fertilised it moves as it becomes an embryo

Because without it; I cannot confess,
To my lover;
All the love I have prepared.

> The eggshell allows the embryo to mature

After I confess;
I part,
And I love.

> When it confesses it breaks apart releasing the egg or the yolk to the world.

not sure but I like that idea :)

Comment: Good job! I really like your answer :) but it’s not the one I was going for :((

Comment: Since when are eggshells pink? I've only ever seen white and brown-ish ones (I guess the brown ones can be considered pink, but they're not really)

Comment: @Riker they aren't fully pink, but I'd say pinkish. Doesn't really matter in the end considering this is wrong :)

Answer (score 4):

As OP has already accepted an answer and it fits perfect, just adding an alternate answer to this.

Is it

> Rose

I am usually roseate,
But not always.

> The flower rose is in rose color as the name implies but also can be seen in colors other than rose.

I am sometimes inconsiderate;
But you need me.

> Rose prickles can hurt you while plucking rose, still you may need it.

I protect my jewel
That sometimes moves

> Refers to the stigma of rose which plays major role in reproduction and it is inside the petals protection.

Because without it; I cannot confess,
To my lover;

> Normally nobody use rose or any other flowers without it's stigma because without that the flower won't have it's natural beauty.

All the love I have prepared.
After I confess;
I part,
And I love.

> cutting the rose from it's stem and giving it to the love.

Comment: Yes! This is a good answer :)))